# NSHTTPURLResponse

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey everbody, i'm trying to treat the response of a http post.
My php is giving a simple message, so, how can i treat it?
I mean, if gives me the "Error" message, do something, or "OK" do another thing.

```
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;  
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];  
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];  
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);

}
if (result == @"Logged") {
    NSLog(@"OK");
}
if (result == @"Error") {
    NSLog(@"No");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `isEqualToString:` method. E.g.:

```
if ([result isEqualToString:@"Logged"]) {
    NSLog(@"OK");
} else if ([result isEqualToString:@"Error"]) {
    NSLog(@"No");
}
```

Comment: Great! Please check the answer as the correct one when you get a chance so I can get credit. Thank you!